# Unable to get header when using axios.create

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js, axios

I created an axios instance in axios.js like following

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "url",
  timeout: 5000,
  headers: {
    authorization:
      "key",
  },
});

export default instance;
```

and I am using this like following

```
const responce = await instance.get(url)
```

but the problem is that my api is unable to access headers and it shows me the error that authorization key is required. My api works fine if I manually pass the header like following

```
 const responce = await instance.get(url, {
        headers: {
          authorization:
            "key",
        },
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
instance.defaults.headers.common['authorization'] = "key";
```

Alternative way

```
const instance = axios.create();

instance.interceptors.request.use(
  function (config) {
    config.baseURL = BASE_URL;
    config.headers =  {
      authorization:
        "key",
    }
    return config;
  },
  function (error) {
    Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default instance;
```

Comment: should I place this inside my axios instance in place of header or inside when I am doing my API call?

Comment: Yes, you can place it after the creation of an instance.

Comment: I have added a second option too, if it works as expected, you can accept this answer as the best answer )

Comment: I tried both methods but it didn't work. could you please tell if I am doing anything wrong here

Comment: I tried both methods but it didn't work. could you please tell if I am doing anything wrong here

Comment: `const instance = axios.create();

instance.interceptors.request.use(
  function (config) {
    config.baseURL = "baseUrl";
    config.headers = {
      authorization:
        "key",
    };
    return config;
  },
  function (error) {
    Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default instance;

const responce = await instance.get(url)`

Comment: Are you getting an error?